# A Cryptic Not-so-mini Cube

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, three-dimensional

A quick teaser, enjoy!

[image]

**Across**
3 Dance bores serious (5)
6 Light angry look (5)
11 Finally asked it to agree (5)
12 Rails - cunning homes of thieves (5)
15 Trap saner design (5)
16 Kingdom with real messy leader (5)

**Down**
1 Earth would heartlessly bear resistance (5)
2 Fruit left precious stone (5)
9 Last deciding competition (5)
10 Keep in cabinets to retrieve (5)
13 One liquid substance becomes a spirit (5)
14 Question the metal bars (5)

**Away**
4 On and on wrapping one vegetable (5)
5 Ten strange odd ears come in (5)
7 To let first literature educator access Stack Exchange (5)
8 Country within Luxor, Ur, altogether (5)

Comment: This was a nice crossword! Relatively easy, but I definitely enjoyed it. I really liked the "spirit" misdirection in 13D, and the smooth surface of 16A and 10D. (9D was sort of a double definition using the same meaning both times though, which is generally discouraged - still gettable, though, and didn't detract from my enjoyment of the puzzle.)

Comment: @Deus thanks! where's the misdirection in 13D tho XD

Comment: The word "spirit" can also mean "alcoholic drink" - I had assumed that was intentional!

Comment: laugh out loud XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solved grid, with explanations:

> [image]
>
>  `*` means anagram; `_` means only part of a word or phrase is taken (due to either first/last letter, hidden word, or odds/evens); `(ddef)` stands for 'double definition'.